# How to display 3 divs per row as screen size gets smaller

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have 6 divs inside a div tag. All those div tags are displayed in one row.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content"> 1 </div>
    <div class="content"> 2 </div>
    <div class="content"> 3 </div>
    <div class="content"> 4 </div>
    <div class="content"> 5 </div>
    <div class="content"> 6 </div>
</div>
```

```
.main{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.content{
    width: 14vw;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```
@media(max-width: 1000px){

}
```

When the screen width equals 1000px, I want to display 3 on top and 3 on bottom.
Is there a way I can do this with CSS without having to add additional HTML tags?

Comment: Have you looked at using media queries?

Comment: inside the media query use a display table layout so that you can choose the number of elements per row

Comment: @Berto99, Thank you. I figured out what I wanted to display with css table display.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.main{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width:100%
}
.content{
    width: 14vw;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   display: inline-block
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
.content{
     width: 25% !important;
     display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a5ymdhL/)